highlight full word
I'm trying to make word highlighting in emacs.
Let's take the example: "fix the radio. radio fixed."
I want to highlight the word "fix", but not the first three letters of the word "fixed".
And this is what happens with the commands "highlight-regexp" e "highlight-phrase".
I have done several searches on the Internet and have not found the answer.
If anyone knows how to resolve the situation, I would be very grateful.
I use the following code:
(highlight-phrase "fix " (quote color-style))

but I understand that this is not smart. It works, but using dot or comma after the word (fix. fix, fix;), this command does not work.

When I use:
(highlight-phrase "fix" (quote color-style))

The result is:


Not sure I understand the part about period and comma, but...
You can just highlight using a regexp that specifies words:
M-x highlight-regexp RET \bfix\b RET RET
The Elisp manual, node Regexp Backslash tells you:

\b
matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a
word.  Thus, \bfoo\b matches any occurrence of foo as a
separate word.  \bballs?\b matches ball or balls as a
separate word.
\b matches at the beginning or end of the buffer (or string)
regardless of what text appears next to it.


It worked perfectly. I am very grateful. Thank you.
P.S. the command (highlight-regexp "\bfix\b" (quote back-red)) works with double backslash.

@alexandre:  In Elisp (strings) you need to double backslashes. If you use highlight-regexp interactively then you don't need to.
